# vsftpd utf8 support

Tags: 18.04, vsftpd

I am on ubuntu 18.04.4. I set the config for vsftpd to use utf8 file system. I set dpkg-reconfigure locales to en_US.UTF-8. I check locales and it is working. I restart vsftpd and try to check the ftp but directories and files are still showing incorrect. ssh and sftp are fine. Can someone please help?